# Split and choose in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split

I found some explanation to do this but i still can't do it !!

I want to split `val data=sc.textFile("hdfs://ncdc/isd-history.csv")`

the `data` have the form :  `("949999","00338","PORTLAND (CASHMORE)","AS","","","-38.320","+141.480","+0081.0","19690724","19781113")`

I want to split data and take only the 1st `(949999)` and the 3rd `(PORTLAND (CASHMORE))`

I have done this ,

```
val RDD = (data.filter(s => (s.split(',')(0) , s.split(',')(2))))
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Any errors? What is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RDD.filter` filters *records*, not "columns" - it expects a function from the record type (String, I assume, in this case) to `Boolean`, and would filter out all records for which this function returned `false`.

You're trying to *transform* each record from a String into a tuple (while "filtering" out parts of that string), so you should use `RDD.map` instead of `RDD.filter`:

```
val RDD = data.map(s => (s.split(',')(0), s.split(',')(2)))
```

Or better yet:

```
val RDD = data.map(_.split(',')).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `split` to split strings and not collections.

If this is a `RDD` of tuples, this should work:

`val RDD = data map(row => (row._1, row._3))`

If this is a `RDD` of `Array/Seq[String]` just sub `_1` and `_3` for indexes `0` and `2`.